# Retrieving transformed dataset from pipeline object in pyspark.ml.pipeline

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, pipeline

I am new to Spark ML. I am trying to make a use of Spark ML Pipelines in order to chain data transformation (think of it as an ETL process). In other words, I would like to input a DataFrame, do a series of transformation (each time adding a column to this dataframe) and output the transformed DataFrame.

I was looking into the documentation and the code for Pipelines in Python, but I did not get how you can get the transformed dataset out of the Pipeline. See the following example (copied from the documentation and modified):

```
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.ml.feature import HashingTF, Tokenizer

# Prepare training documents from a list of (id, text, label) tuples.
training = spark.createDataFrame([
   (0, "a b c d e spark", 1.0),
   (1, "b d", 0.0),
   (2, "spark f g h", 1.0),
   (3, "hadoop mapreduce", 0.0)
    ], ["id", "text", "label"])

 # Configure an ML pipeline, which consists of two stages: tokenizer, 
 hashingTF.
 tokenizer = Tokenizer(inputCol="text", outputCol="words")
 hashingTF = HashingTF(inputCol=tokenizer.getOutputCol(), 
 outputCol="features")
 pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[tokenizer, hashingTF])

 training.show()
 pipeline.fit(training)
```

How can I get the transformed dataset (i.e. a dataset after the tokenizer and hashing has been carried out) from the "pipeline" object?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot. Instead preserve the model

```
model = pipeline.fit(training)
```

and use it to `transform` data:

```
training_transformed = model.transform(training)
```

Comment: Thx a lot, that is what I was looking for!